# Stack not succeding in pushing a number into it

Tags: c, arrays, stack, push, bucket

I am trying to make a "bucket" that holds the elements in an array and when I access the push function I want to place the x element in that array. I don't understand why the array remains empty all the time. It prints for this input:

" /n
  /n
  /n
  The stack is empty!
  Popped: -9999
  \n
  \n 
  \n
  \n
  \n
  The stack is empty!
  Popped: -9999
  \n
  \n
  \n
  \n
  \n
  \n
"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct stivaStack
{
    int arr[10];
    int len;
}stivaStack_t;


void printStiva(stivaStack_t S)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<S.len;i++)
        printf("%d ",S.arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void stivaPush(int x, stivaStack_t S)
{
    if (S.len+1<10)
    {
        int a=S.len;
        S.arr[a]=x;
        S.len=a+1;
    }
    else
    printf("The stack is full can't place %d!\n",x);
}

int stivaPop(stivaStack_t S)
{
    if (S.len>0)
    {
        S.len--;
        return S.arr[S.len];
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The stack is empty!\n");
        return -9999;
    }
}

int main()
{

    stivaStack_t SS;
    SS.len=0;

    stivaPush(102,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(25,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(9,SS); printStiva(SS);
    printf("Popped: %d\n",stivaPop(SS)); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(3,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(12,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(29,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(40,SS); printStiva(SS);
    printf("Popped: %d\n",stivaPop(SS)); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(155,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(4,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(19,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(25,SS); printStiva(SS);
    stivaPush(49,SS); printStiva(SS);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to pass the stack by reference not by value.  For example void stivaPush(int x, stivaStack_t *S); Otherwise the functions deal with a copy of the stack.

Comment: Take into account that this condition  if (S.len+1<10) in the function stivaPush should be changed to if (S.len < 10)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you, that might be one of the problems. I tried to change it but I now receive errors saying I request for member len in something not a structure or union. After I pass it by reference as a parameter how should I acces those values (len, arr) within the function? Neither S.len or *S.len don't work.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I would prefer not to use the "pass by reference" terminology as C doesn't actually do references.

Comment: @AndreiSold If you are using a pointer then the syntax is changed, For example S->len. or ( *S).len

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Why not to use the C terminology when C is discussed?:)

Comment: (*S).len within the function and passing the adress of the stack in the main calls is the solution. Thank you very much @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @VladfromMoscow "Pass by reference" is C++ terminology as far as I am aware.  C always passes by value; when you pass in a pointer to an object, you are passing a pointer by value as opposed to passing a reference, which does not exist in C.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You are mistaken. Referenced types is also a C terminology. For example (the C Standard) "...— A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the
referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
to an entity of the referenced type...."

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I may be getting pedantic at this point, but the 'referenced type' is simply reflecting back on what type a pointer is pointing to.  Use of the term 'referenced type' does not bring in "pass by reference".  When doing a search for "C pass by reference", I find most results to be people trying to use C++'s pass-by-reference mechanism in C which does not have such mechanism in the language (which is what I am trying to prevent by not using the term when dealing with C).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow One exception I will note came from here: http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language:Terms:Pass_by_reference which does have a page for `pass by reference` in C, but also comes with this note: 'Referring to the C mechanism used in the example above - passing a pointer to a variable in order to access the variable within the function - as "pass by reference" is technically incorrect. [...] Better and more correct is to refer to the C mechanism as "passing a reference". '

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You are trying to speak about C using C++ terminology. It is a wrong approach. Pass by reference in C means  passing an argument using a pointer because as I already showed the quote "...A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type...."  and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions deal with copies of the stack instead of the original stack itself.

You have to pass the stack by reference to the functions.

For example

```
void stivaPush(int x, stivaStack_t *S)
{
    if (S->len < 10)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        int a = S->len;
        S->arr[a]=x;
        S->len=a+1;
    }
    else
    printf("The stack is full can't place %d!\n",x);
}
```

And a function call can look like

```
stivaPush(102, &SS);
```

Also it is a bad idea when the functions issue a message.

The function above could be defined like

```
int stivaPush( stivaStack_t *S, int x )
{
    int success = S->len < 10;

    if ( success )
    {
        S->arr[len++] = x;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I don't understand why the array remains empty all the time.

Because you pass the variable to the function by value. By that we mean, you call the function with the variable, in the called function there is another function with the same content as this one. And then you work on it. On the copy. Function ends. Copy is thrown away. That's end. The original variable is still the same.

#### How to solve that?

Well simulate pass by reference in C by passing the address of the variable. Well, without complicating things the simple way to understand this is, instead of passing the variable's value you pass the variable's address. Here also, there is a local variable in the called function which has same content as that of the address of the variable. Now you access the address via that copy of the variable which contains the address. You make changes to the variable that is being stored in that address. So the changes you make stays.

#### How to do that?

Well it's given in the other answer. The answer shows how to do it with code. Not repeating content.